# Genexus X Ev. 3 - Problemas na leitura de Excel(xls)

Tags: microsoft-excel, iis, genexus, xls

Olá, 
Estou com um problema na leitura de xls, fica só carregando e aparece na parte inferior do browser "Aguardando localhost(ou o servidor)", fiz o teste com xlsx funciona normal.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já fiz testes em outros navegadores e em outras maquinas com sistemas operacionais diferentes, mas sem sucesso.
Estou utilizando IIS7, Gerando .net, BD PostgreSQL, Genexus X Ev. 3 U9;